# Current page using MuPDF

Tags: android, mupdf

I'm using MuPDF to open and edit PDFs in my android application, but I need of some way to get the current page in a bitmap format.

I've been reading the code, but I've not succeed. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a similar feature in our Android customizable magazine app, using muPDF: we generate page thumbnails in bitmap format.
This app is open source and available on [Github](https://github.com/libreliodev/android). You can see there how we implemented this feature.

Comment: The method drawSinglePage of MuPDFCore, worked for me.
Thank you!

Comment: @DeboraMartins I can't find drawSinglePage method in whole project! Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858689/using-mupdf-with-curl-flip-effect

Comment: @Librelio Does it have curl/flip effect, with/without search option?

Answer (score 2):

The MuPDF API is a C level one. It's certainly capable of doing what you want - see apps/mudraw.c for code that does this, or even doc/render.c.

In the example android viewer, we needed to be able to do some things from java. So, we wrapped up a small fraction of the API with jni and exposed that (see android/jni/mupdf.c). This does just enough for what we need, and nothing more.

If you want to get access to parts of the API that aren't exposed, (and it sounds to me like you do) then you'll have to wrap up that for yourself.

In an ideal world, we'd have it set up so that there was a direct mapping from java classes down to the underlying MuPDF API, but we haven't had the time/need to do that yet. If anyone out there is interested in doing such a thing, do get in touch...